# Unit velocity parametrization of a parabola.

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I have a parametrization for the parabola $y = x^2$ given by:
$$x(t) = t$$
$$y(t) = t^2$$
However, this doesn't have constant unit velocity, since $$\sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2} = \sqrt{1 + 4t^2} \neq 1\,.$$
Is there a way to fix this so that the velocity is 1 for all $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...in theory. If you define the *arclength function*
$$
s = f(t)
  = \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{1 + 4\tau^{2}}\, d\tau
  = t\sqrt{1 + 4t^{2}} + \tfrac{1}{4}\ln\left(t + \sqrt{1 + 4t^{2}}\right)
$$
and put $t = g(s) = f^{-1}(s)$ (which in general is "practically impossible"), then
$$
\bigl(g(s), g^{2}(s)\bigr)
$$
is a unit-speed parametrization. (The same trick works—subject to the same obstacle—for an arbitrary smooth curve whose speed is non-vanishing.)